# Formula - Omit values until new month begins

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm looking to omit existing values until a new month begins.

Currently YTD Plan =Sum(H4:Q4) I'm summing values from Jan through Oct. When the new month begins (November) is there a formula or function that will update T4 automatically? The values are already there so just need to omit or not include R4 and S4 until those months begin. Is there a way or function to accomplish this so that I won't have to modify or extend the formula every time a new month begins? Thank you

Updated Picture from recent comment - 11/4

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works for you. Sample data as in below screenshot.

[image]

Formula in P4 is

```
=SUM(INDEX(D4:O4,1):INDEX(D4:O4,MONTH(NOW())))
```

However even if the calculation is set to automatic, you need to open the sheet  or at least update it to get the update to the formula. So if month changes from Oct to Nov, you should either press F9 or edit the data or re-open the sheet for the formula to update.

**Edit - Based on more inputs in Comments**

See the below screenshot and the recorded screen.

[image]

[image]

In Q2 Data Validation List is added with Values as Planned, Actual.

Formula in P4 is

```
=IF(Q2="Planned",SUM(INDEX(D4:O4,1):INDEX(D4:O4,MONTH(NOW()))),SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(D5:O5),D4:O4,0)))
```

This is an Array Formula, so you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the Formula Bar to create this Array Formula. The formula shall be automatically enclosed in Curly Braces to indicate that it's an array formula. This step is important, else it will not work correctly.

Now based one the Selection from Drop Down

If Planned is selected, the SUM of Planned up to the actual Current Month is reflected in Planned YTD.

If Actual is selected then SUM of all Planned values for which corresponding Actual values exist is reflected  in Planned YTD.

Comment: Fantastic, this worked. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Is there a way to set it by when the Act Data comes for the month? Looking at the screenshot I shared, when data for P5 is available, YTD Plan (T4) updates

Comment: In that case I assume you do not want the condition based on the actual time. Instead as you populate the Actual row cells for each month the SUM should advance?

Comment: I want the condition based on the actual time.I asked for an alternative method or formula because sometimes I don’t get the reports on time, I still don’t have the Actual # for the month of Sept and Oct (P5 Q5) while the Plan # are all there (Jan-Dec) Maybe there’s an alternative I could use when the reports come late; the YTD Plan (T4) will update based on when the monthly data comes for the Actuals, something like T4 sums H4 through P4 when P5 data is there and so forth - The following month T4 will sum H4 through Q4 when Q5 values are added for that month. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Both arguments will be valid, it would be nice to know both so I can use them based on either circumstance

Comment: Will something like this work? You get a Drop down to choose Plan or Actual for Planned YTD value. If you Select Plan the SUM up to current actual Month (real time) is Planned YTD. If you choose Actual, then regardless of the current month, SUM of all Actual (only till updated) will be shown as Planned YTD in T4?

Comment: Yes, something like that will work

Comment: See the edit. Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome! This is super helpful, I can use both. Thank you!!!!